# CosmosDB SQL API Insert or Merge

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, upsert

We've decided to move from Azure Table Storage (ATS) to CosmosDB in certain cases. I am trying to figure out, how to imitate ATS `InsertOrMerge` operation in CosmosDB SQL API. Using `UpsertItemAsync` actually replaces the item (if found).

To illustrate the problem, let's imagine that app1 creates an item of 3 not null fields in CosmosDB. app2 wants to update the item, but has an item of 2 not null fields (e.g. one of them being id to match the previous record).  `InsertOrMerge` from ATS would result in 2 new not null fields and the remaining field would be from the app1 item (not null) field. `UpsertItemAsync` from Cosmos will simply replace the item (losing the third field).

Of course, this could be done by first getting the item, merging it with the new object and replacing the new item, but this means one more call. Is there a way to do this without first retrieving the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Partial Document Update` functionality in Cosmos DB however that is currently in private preview (at the time of answering this question).

You can learn more about this functionality and how to enable your account for this functionality, please see this link: https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/PatchPrivatePreviewFeedbackGroup.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you have any idea when this will be a part of the stable package (and not in preview mode)? Or, is there any chance that this functionality won't be released at all (hopefully not)? Not sure if we can rely on it in production apps..

Comment: I would let someone from Cosmos DB answer that.

Comment: This really can't be answered by anyone here, even someone from the Cosmos DB team - that's a roadmap/planning question.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this as another answer specifying the method and sample.

As `@Gaurav` mentioned, this is where you could utilize the [Partial Document Update Patch API](https://github.com/AzureCosmosDB/PatchPrivatePreviewFeedbackGroup#conditional-patch-syntax-based-on-filter-predicate) feature with Cosmosdb. What you are looking for is the Replace method

```
cosmosPatchOperations.replace("/taskNum", newTaskNum);
```

Also you can use Conditional Patch Operation command to replace a property.

Comment: Hello. I can see that you also answered my question in MS Q&A. Maybe follow up question, I registered through the form in the link you provided, however, I haven't received confirmation yet. Can be this the reason I am getting 400 - bad request (without any reason) when trying to perform patch operations?

Comment: Yes correct  , can you provide your subscription id to check internally if this has been activated. Also you can test Patch API with emulator by running /EnablePatchPreview